# C# Insert text lines before a certain word

Tags: c#, file, text, append

I currently have a app that creates lines of code and at the moment it uses `File.AppendAllText(newPathName, sptData);
 File.AppendAllText(newPathName, string.Format("{0}{1}", " ", Environment.NewLine));` to add those new lines to the bottom of the document.

How can I get it to insert the data before the line with "PROC" you see below? Please note that the file will not always have the same data in but will always have the word **PROC** which is why it needs to be before that.

!# -----------------------------------------------
!# ------ WOBJ DATA
!# -----------------------------------------------
PERS wobjdata w_td97200:=[False,True,"",[[-854.99,1926.58,592.01],[0.737197,0,0,0.675677]],[[0,0,0],[1,0,0,0]]];
  PERS wobjdata w_tc97200:=[False,True,"",[[-463.99,1486.54,229.27],[0.298836,0.640862,0.298836,-0.640852]],[[0,0,0],[1,0,0,0]]];

**INSERT NEW TEXT HERE**

**PROC** P13_a_rsw01_200_l538com()
     !========
     ! PROG_INFO : L538 STN200

Comment: What about foreach loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm...

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\1.txt").ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
{
    if (lines[i].StartsWith("PROC"))
    {
        lines.Insert(i, "NEW TEXT");
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be `lines.Insert(i, "NEW TEXT");` to place the new line before the PROC line.

Comment: No, insert displaces the elements one, if you find the line at index 2 you want the new line to be at index 2 and the old at index 3. Else, think of this, you can't use a negative index, if you want to add before index 0 it would be impossible.